# WordPress Integration in ASP.net 4.0 & SQL Server 2008 website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, wordpress, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to integrate WordPress in a website which is running on .net framework 4.0 and using SQL Server 2008 as its database.

Can anybody suggest me a reference so that I can proceed in right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for WordPress are PHP and either MySQL or MariaDB for your database.

https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

The Microsoft web server, IIS, allows both of these to be installed.